# Magento products creation software

Tags: magento

I would like to insert some products into Magento store. I want to populate the store by importing products from CSV file. Is there any user-friendly software that can help me in creating list of products with all defined earlier attributes and images and next convert it into CSV or XML file.
I can do it in Excel or OpenOffice but I look for window/table software tool that can facilitate product creation with thumbnail images of products
that I describe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import products in mass using magmi
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Just you have to put magmi folder in root directory

Below is the Documentation of magmi

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Hope this will server your purpose.